# Getting cURL error 56: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer error when I want to send request to other service

Tags: docker, nginx, containers, microservices

I researched a lot but I didn't find any solution to solve my problem so I decided to ask a question here. I have 2 services that are written in Lumen and They're correctly running with docker.
This is my product service's `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:

product_nginx:
  image: nginx:alpine
  container_name: product_nginx
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www
    - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
  depends_on:
    - product_app
    - product_db
  networks:
    - shopnet

product_app:
  container_name: product_app
  build: 
    context: ./php
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  working_dir: /var/www
  expose:
    - 9000
  networks:
    - shopnet

networks:
  shopnet:
    external: true
```

There is a route that is just for returning a string in product service:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
   $router->group(['prefix' => 'products'], function () use ($router) {
      $router->get('/', function () {
        return 'List of Products';
      });
   });
});
```

and Here is the `nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 index index.php index.htm index.html;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
 server_name localhost;
 root /var/www/public;

 location /index.php {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass product_app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
 }
}
```

The second service has the same structure but its web server is running on port `8888` with `gateway_nginx` name and the app service has `gateway_app` name and is running on `port 9002`, I want to send a request to the product service. with the below code:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router)
 {
   $router->group(['prefix' => 'service1'], function () use ($router)
   {
    $router->get('/', function()
    {
        $response = Http::get('http://product_app:9000/api/products');
        return $response;
     });
  });
});
```

But after calling the `127.0.0.1:8888/api/service1` I get the below error:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you check in the logs of the `product_app` service for the cause of the 500?

Comment: The product_app is running without any error on port `8080`.